# Comparing value to previous and printing whether it is same or different

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I need to determine whether the output "On" or "Off" is the same as the previous cell and if it is the same then print "Same Cycle" or if it is different print "Different cycle". I am in jupyter python and my current code is:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

header_list = ['Time']

df = pd.read_csv('S8-1.csv' , skiprows=6 , names = header_list)#splits the data into proper columns

df[['Date/Time','Pressure']] = df.Time.str.split(",,", expand=True)#deletes orginal messy column
df.pop('Time')
#convert Pressure from object to numeric

df['Pressure'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Pressure'], errors = 'coerce')#converts to a time

df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date/Time'], format = '%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S.%f' , errors = 'coerce')

df['Moving Average'] = df['Pressure'].rolling(window=5).mean()

df['Rolling Average Center']= df['Pressure'].rolling(window=5, center=True).mean()

df['Machine On/Off'] = ['1' if x >= 115 else '0' for x in df['Rolling Average Center'] ]

df['Moving Avg of Binary'] = df['Machine On/Off'].rolling(window=3).mean()

df['On/Off'] = ['On' if x > 0 else 'Off' for x in df ['Moving Avg of Binary']]

df['Cycle change'] = ['Same Cycle' if x == last else 'New Cycle' for x != last in df['On/Off']]
```

Where the last line is giving me trouble. My data looks as such: [Excel Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObfLX.png)

Comment: could you provide a sample dataframe?  And you can delete all the lines which aren't related to `on/off` in your code: they're not relevant to this problem.  What exactly is the problem you're having?

Comment: Was the answer helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow, Lets assume your dataframe is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 
your_dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'your_on/of_column':['ON', 'OFF', 'ON', 'ON', 'OFF', 'ON', 'ON', 'OFF', 'ON']})
your_dataframe['other_column1'] = ['foo' for item in range(len(your_dataframe))]
your_dataframe['other_column2'] = ['bar' for item in range(len(your_dataframe))]
######
  your_on/of_column other_column1 other_column2
0                ON           foo           bar
1               OFF           foo           bar
2                ON           foo           bar
3                ON           foo           bar
4               OFF           foo           bar
5                ON           foo           bar
6                ON           foo           bar
7               OFF           foo           bar
8                ON           foo           bar
```

There is a famous function for determining the difference between consecutive values named `diff` which you can read about [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html)!.
The only thing to notice is that it can only operate on numeric/logical values So convert the column `your_on/of_column` to boolean values and go ahead!

```
your_dataframe['Cycle'] = your_dataframe['your_on/of_column'].apply(lambda item:item=='ON').diff().apply(lambda item:"Different Cycle" if item else "Same Cycle")
```

output:

```
  your_on/of_column other_column1 other_column2            Cycle
0                ON           foo           bar  Different Cycle
1               OFF           foo           bar  Different Cycle
2                ON           foo           bar  Different Cycle
3                ON           foo           bar       Same Cycle
4               OFF           foo           bar  Different Cycle
5                ON           foo           bar  Different Cycle
6                ON           foo           bar       Same Cycle
7               OFF           foo           bar  Different Cycle
8                ON           foo           bar  Different Cycle
```